# Usar profiling do Maven ou do Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Nas minhas pesquisas eu pude entender que há como realizar profiling da aplicação (ex. homologação e produção) de duas formas, via maven e spring-boot. A grande questão é que eu tenho multiplos perfis e gostaria de empacotar cada um corretamente. Qual devo usar? Como devo usar esse recurso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade,se você quer já empacotar em um profile específico, você utilizará os dois.

A primeira forma é através do próprio Spring Boot, criando vários arquivos .properties no modelo `applications-{profile}.properties`

Por exemplo, temos um arquivo para configuração do ambiente de produção `application-prd.properties` e um arquivo para configuração do ambiente de homologação `application-hml.properties`

E para que a aplicação use as configurações de produção ou de ambiente, deve-se acrescentar no comando java:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active={profile} aplicacao.jar
```

Por exemplo:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prd aplicacao.jar
```

Até aqui conseguimos executar nossa aplicação em cada profile que tivermos. Mas perceba que esse recurso de profiling do spring boot é para ser utilizado em tempo de execução (runtime) e não te possibilita a fazer packaging já em um profile específico. É nesse caso que entra o profiling do maven no arquivo `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>lcl</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>lcl</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>hml</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>hml</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prd</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prd</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Mas isso não basta, tudo o que fizemos ali foi criar uma "variável" chamada `activatedProperties` que dependendo do profile recebe um valor. Diante disso, vamos criar um `application.properties`, que é o arquivo de configuração default para leitura do Spring Boot e será lido no lugar dos outros 3 que criamos e vamos informar lá a variável do spring `spring.profiles.active`, a que estávamos configurando durante o modo de execução, e passar essa "variável" `activatedProperties`. Nosso arquivo `application-properties.xml` ficaria assim:

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

O maven não fará a substituição da "variável" delimitada entre os @s enquanto não informarmos para ele filtrar esses arquivos. Sendo assim, também no `pom.xml` adicionaremos um `<resource>`:

```
<build>

    ...

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Pronto, agora sim. Podemos fazer o package através do comando:

```
mvn package -P{profile}
```

Por exemplo:

```
mvn package -Pprd
```

Quando formos executar esse comando acontecerá basicamente o seguinte:

- Comando `mvn package -Pprd` é executado.
- O maven irá ver qual o profile estamos solicitando através de `-P{profile}` que é o profile `prd`.
- O maven irá descobrir o valor da variável `activatedProperties` daquele profile.
- O maven irá *scanear* todos os arquivos dentro de `src/main/resources` e identificará no arquivo `application.properties` o delimitador `@activatedProperties@` e irá literalmente substituir pelo valor a variável `activatedProperties`.
- Spring Boot irá ser executado
- Spring Boot irá fazer a leitura do arquivo de configuração default `application.properties` encontrado.
- Nesse arquivo haverá a seguinte configuração: `spring.profiles.active=prd` e, com isso, o arquivo `application-prd.properties` será lido.

Answer (score 1):

Também pode configurar em apenas um application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${activatedProperties}

---

spring:
  profiles: homolog    
logging:
  file: /springLogs/autenticador.log
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: debug
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %msg%n'

---

spring:
  profiles: production    
logging:
  file: E:/java/logs/wildfly-10.0.0/autenticador/autenticador.log
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: debug
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %msg%n'
```